# RegularExpression для игнорирования HTML тегов

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net, asp.net-mvc

Нужно запретить ввод HTML тегов в текстовое поле,
делаю через RegularExpression.

```
Display(Name = "Текст")]
DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле должно быть установлено")]
RegularExpression(@"<[^>]*>", ErrorMessage = "HTML теги не допустимы")]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Но на стороне клиента всё равно добавляются теги и отправляются на сервер, а там уже происходит исключение HttpRequestValidationException "Обнаружено потенциально опасное значение".

Comment: А почему обязательно исключить? Почему бы серверу не обрабатывать правильно **любой** текст? Иначе к вашему серверу можно будет подключиться telnet'ом и передать текст, обойдя вашу валидацию (и потенциально нарушив безопасность).

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, атрибут RegularExpression проверяет входные данные на соответствие регулярному выражению, т.е. если во входной строке будут только теги, то строка пройдет валидацию на клиенте.

Comment: т.е. нужно поставить отрицание, а как это сделать?

Comment: Можно попробовать вот такую регулярку ([\w\s\d]+(?![^<>]*>)), будет выбирать только буквы, цифры и пробелы и исключать теги и то, что в них.